# Writing to local file system in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('https') > -1) {
        var tabURL = tab.url;
        console.log("\n<TimeStamp>" + getTimestamp() + "</TimeStamp><Browser>Chrome</Browser><URL>" + tabURL + "</URL>\n");
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024, initFs);

        function initFs(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile
            ('log.txt', { create: true, exclusive: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.isFile = true;
                fileEntry.name = 'log.txt';
                fileEntry.fullPath = '/log.txt';
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                    bb.append("\n<TimeStamp>" + getTimestamp() + "</TimeStamp><Browser>Chrome</Browser><URL>" + tabURL + "</URL>\n");
                    fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing a Chrome extension?  If so, please specify that (in a tag and/or in the question).

Comment: Try adding an error callback to the requestFileSystem call to display any errors.

Comment: I have edited changes to my question,previous problem have been solved & I have been faced with a new problem. Do guide me along,thank you in advance.

Comment: If your question was answered you should close it and open a new one. In any case I see your code, what is the question.

Comment: Is there any way to access this file from a endows application not running in the browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this:

> At the time of writing this article,
>   Google Chrome 9+ has the only working
>   implementation of the FileSystem API.
>   Since a dedicated browser UI does not
>   yet exist for file/quota management,
>   the API cannot be used without running
>   Chrome with the
>   --unlimited-quota-for-files flag (Note: if you're building an app or
>   extension for the Chrome Web Store,
>   the unlimitedStorage manifest file
>   permission will suffice).

found at http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-support

I assume you are using Chrome and that you have not set the --unlimited-quota-for-files flag

Comment: If I were to add the permission "unlimitedStorage" in the manifest file,it would prompt me " Manifest is not valid JSON, syntex error. Whats the problem ?

Comment: The manifest file must be valid JSON syntax. See here : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Comment: I have edited changes to my question,previous problem have been solved & I have been faced with a new problem. Do guide me along,thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

This filesystem API does not appear to actually write a true "file" to your hard disk.
It seems to store a file within a sandboxed safe zone in the browser.
You'll have to write a quick and dirty little file manager (or find one out there) to manage the files for a given web app. You can also try visiting `filesystem://<your URL here>/temporary/` to see all the files that your app has created.

Comment: One change: filesystem:http//<your URL here>/temporary/

Comment: can the written file be accessed from outside the browser? Let's say I write a text file, can I open it in an external text editor somehow?

Answer (score 1):

What about just using [localStorage](http://julianapena.com/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-2-options-and-localstorage/)?

Comment: I have seen the tutorial on the HTML5 fileSystem API on writing the file to the local system,I believed I followed every step but I havent been able to see my log file inside my local system. Any advice ?

Comment: I have edited changes to my question,previous problem have been solved & I have been faced with a new problem. Do guide me along,thank you in advance.

Comment: localStorage is probably the easiest option. Only disadvantage is that is limited to 5 MB, even after specifying the `"unlimitedStorage"` permission. Use it like this:
`localStorage["log"] = "Hello World!"` to write, and
`log = localStorage["log"]` to read.